Block Smooth Transition
I have this codepen
https://codepen.io/sirlouen/pen/rNbdGmB
After trying on multiple ways, I cannot figure out how to make the block transition smoothly from bottom to top, instead of popping instantly.


.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.text-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: display 0.5s ease-in-out; /* This doesn't work */
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none; /* Hide initially */
  margin-top: 10px; /* Add spacing between visible and hidden texts */
}

.image-container:hover .hidden-text {
  display: block; /* Show on hover */
}

.image-container:hover .arrow {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease; /* Smooth transition to hide for the arrow */
  opacity: 0;
}
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="text-content">
    <span class="visible-text">Visible text <span class="arrow">▼</span></span>
    <span class="hidden-text">This is some additional text that will be revealed when you hover over the visible part.</span>
  </div>
</div>



After reading, I found that display don't apply transitions
Transitions on the CSS display property
Css transition from display none to display block, navigation with subnav
But not 100% sure how could I apply this visibility mechanism to my scenario. Because in those cases, the text only appears from hidden. But in my case, the block actually moves upwards (which is what I want to transition, not only the text itself)
I've seen some options using max-height and transitioning this property, but I feel is not a adequate solution because I'm forced to a given height instead of adapting to the text that is already visible (unless I'm missing something)
This is the idea: https://codepen.io/sirlouen/pen/ExJEwdy
However, I have adjusted it to 25% for max-height which is not ideal. If Visible text had two lines, the arrow would be hidden because it will go under the max-height.
Any ideas to sort this?

Try this

You can apply the transition to max-height and use overflow: hidden.
You have a fixed height for the .image-container, so use the same value for the max-height of the .hidden-text. You can make use of a css variable to insure this happens.


:root {
  --image-container-height: 200px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: var(--image-container-height);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.text-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: block;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.image-container:hover .hidden-text {
  /* Show on hover */
  max-height: var(--image-container-height);
}

.hidden-text:hover {
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-container .arrow {
  transition: opacity 0.75s ease;
  /* Smooth transition to hide and show the arrow */
}

.image-container:hover .arrow {
  opacity: 0;
}
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="text-content">
    <span class="visible-text">Visible text <span class="arrow">▼</span></span>
    <span class="hidden-text">This is some additional text that will be revealed when you hover over the visible part.</span>
  </div>
</div>




Yesterday I was trying the same approach but instead of using 200px for max-height in the :hoverpart, I set it to 100% which didn't work. Isn't 100% the same to 200px? Because when I set max-height to 100% in the class .hidden-text it actually expands well, but not if I set the 100% in the :hover part.
Problem is that I don't really know exactly the max-height always. I put 200px for the example. but I need a more generalistic option.
